# Titanium Alloy - How do I best assign a click event to an Option on a Option Dialog?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In Titanium Alloy, I have an OptionDialog for some filter options. But I'm not sure how to add click events each of the options, according to best practice.

**View**

```
<OptionDialog id="filterDialog" title="Filter">
    <Options>
        <Option id="byDate">Date added</Option>
        <Option>Rating - high first</Option>
        <Option>Rating - low first</Option>
        <Option>Cancel</Option>
    </Options>  
</OptionDialog>
```

**Controller**

```
$.byDate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Filter by date');
});
```

But the above event listerner causes the following error:

```
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.byDate.addEventListener');
```

What's the **best practice** for assigning a click event to each of these options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create eventListener attached to OptionDialog, not every single Option and then check value of event.index property:

```
$.filterDialog.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    switch (event.index) {
        case 0:
            alert('Date added selected')
            break;
        case 1:
            alert('Rating - hight selected')
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Rating - low selected')
            break;     
    }
});
```

Also remember to set [OptionDialog.cancel property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.OptionDialog-property-cancel) and Titanium SDK will handle Cancel button automatically. In your case you can add it to `<OptionDialog>`:

```
<OptionDialog id="filterDialog" title="Filter" cancel="3">
```